# Material UI - Align icon to center with the Typography text

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-icons

How do I align icon to the same level as the text. As of now, I see the icon is at little top to the text. I tried to use `padding-top: 5px` and also `margin-top: 5px` but that does not seem to work as expected.

```
  <Box>
    <Typography variant="h2">
      Photography <FaCamera />
    </Typography>
  </Box>
```

I created a working example using [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/icon-postion-with-text?file=src/App.js). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 6):

```
<Typography variant="h2">
  Photography <FaCamera  style={{verticalAlign:"middle"}}/>
</Typography>
```

you can try inline style 'verticalAlign', it is works for me .

Answer (score 4):

I was able to align it correctly using `position` and `top` properties of CSS.

```
<Box>
  <Typography variant="h2">
    Photography <FaCamera style={{position: 'relative', top: '8px'}} />
  </Typography>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use a Grid to achieve the correct alignment without the need for any CSS.

```
<Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
   <Grid item>
      <Typography variant="h2">
         Photography
      </Typography>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item>
      <FaCamera />
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when importing icons from `@mui/icons-material`.

Setting `fontSize: 'inherit'` makes the icon the same size as the font. There was still a slight vertical alignment issue which I was able to resolve by using `verticalAlign: 'text-top'`.

Code that worked for me was:

```
<Icon sx={{ fontSize: 'inherit', verticalAlign: 'text-top' }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a `fontSize="inherit"` on your inline-icon like : `<FaCamera fontSize="inherit" />`